# Why is my month filter method is give me data from 2 months?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am now trying to filter the result and giving back the data,

Sometimes right now the app is giving me data from 2 months

here is the data

```
[
    [
        "Sun Feb 28 2021",
        [
            {
                "_id": "603b91d1b9903923e0c78b54",
                "expense_name": "Buy Water",
                "amount": 400,
                "shop_id": "603a3d23e88ac21eb8dade80",
                "createdAt": "2021-02-28T12:51:29.199Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-28T12:51:29.199Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "603b91d1b9903923e0c78b55",
                "expense_name": "Buy Rice",
                "amount": 500,
                "shop_id": "603a3d23e88ac21eb8dade80",
                "createdAt": "2021-02-28T12:51:29.199Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-28T12:51:29.199Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Mon Mar 01 2021",
        [
            {
                "_id": "603cf0f9d78fd04a14b2057b",
                "expense_name": "Buy Ammo",
                "amount": 400,
                "shop_id": "603a3d23e88ac21eb8dade80",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-01T13:49:45.045Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-01T13:49:45.045Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "603cf0f9d78fd04a14b2057c",
                "expense_name": "Buy Ovaltine",
                "amount": 500,
                "shop_id": "603a3d23e88ac21eb8dade80",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-01T13:49:45.045Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-01T13:49:45.045Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

here is my date filter method. IDK what is wrong with my method. From my understanding it is pretty correct. The thing is maybe **mongo is saving data in UTC format** and the data return got messed up?

```
    const match = {
      shop_id: req.params.shop_id,
    };
    let beforeString, afterString, params, date, filter_by;

    params = req.query;
    filter_by = params.filter_by;
    date = new Date(params.date);
    if (filter_by == "date") {
      beforeString = date;
      afterString = new Date(date.getTime() + 86400000);
    } else {
      beforeString = new Date(date.setDate(1));
      afterString = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, 1);
    }
    match.createdAt = {
      $gte: moment(beforeString, "YYYY/MM/DD"),
      $lt: moment(afterString, "YYYY/MM/DD"),
    };
    Expense.find(match)
      //   Return someting in json format
      .then((expense) => { .....
```

The route I am calling now is the month february

`{{url}}/shop/{{ID}}/?filter_by=month&date=2021/02/20`

Comment: Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] of just the object and the filter method(s) (and moment CDN). Why post all that node and stuff if this is a JS Filter question?

Comment: You already identified the problem.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry I thought It will be helpful to the person who is answering

Comment: @D.SM What do you mean, did saving data in `UTC format` is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from this row:

```
afterString = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 2, 1);
```

You are adding two months here instead of one, with your current input you will receive this:

```
beforeString = "2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z";
afterDate = "2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z";
```

Hence fetching you both feb and march data, you should just change that row to:

```
afterString = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
```